# How to avoid triggering my server's firewall with post?

Tags: php, javascript, post, validation

So we get a weekly report of all the new books added to our library's collection. 100+ including duplicates. I can pass these fairly easily and clean it up w/ PHP before uploading it to the database, but a small snag is that if a book's title starts with Kill (*Kill me if you can* by Patterson FREX) it will trigger the server's firewall (Modsecurity in this case).

I assume my only option to "pre-clean" the data before submitting it would be JS/jQuery...
So what other words are likely to make the firewall think it's an SQL injection, and how could I massage the data so that it's safe to pass via post? My first inclination is just to search through the data and change `kill` to `XXkillXX` and then in the php look for `XXkillXX` and change it back to just `kill`.

```
<form method="post" action="?action=addnewbooks&amp;submit=validate">
    <textarea name="newbooklist" rows="30" cols="68"></textarea>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="8" maxlength="50"></input>
    <button type="submit" name="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the ModSecurity log file and see which rule you are hitting. Maybe you can solve it by using another parameter name, or by changing the offending firewall rule.